# Gatsby v1 and netlify continuous integration

Tags: gatsby, netlify

I have a website running on gatsby v1 and deployed on netlify. I can't update the site anymore because netlify return an **error 127** on build.

I think it relates to the last gatsby update to v2. Do you know if there is a way to keep using netlify continuous deployment without having to migrate my site to gatsby v2?

Thanks .

Comment: Can you supply more details on the error? This is not enough information to answer this question.

Comment: If your repository is public, you could link to the logs page in Netlify for best advice here.  Or, you could contact the helpdesk (support@netlify.com).  It is almost certainly not required by Netlify to change versions of anything you don't want to, particularly if it worked in the past.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I am not sure what happened . but i had to delete my "node-modules" folder and  "package-lock.json" . and fixed various errors during the new "npm install" locally . After that, the build went fine on netlify without any migration on gatsby v2.